# How to call readEntity on a Response twice?

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jax-rs, httpresponse

What I'm doing right now is resulting in a:

```
java.io.IOException: stream is closed
```

on the 2nd readEntity() since it closes the stream after the first read.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
Response response = target.queryParam("start", startIndex)
   .queryParam("end", end)
   .request()
   .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
   .header(authorizationHeaderName, authorizationHeaderValue)
   .get();

String xml = response.readEntity(String.class);
ourLogger.debug(xml);


MyClass message = response.readEntity(MyClass.class); //throws IOException
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your comment until after I posted this.  Your solution does work.  If you put it as an answer to this questions I will upvote it and select it as correct.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

/You can use [`Response#bufferEntity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#bufferEntity--), which will allow you to read the entity stream multiple times.

```
Response response = ...
response.bufferEntity();
String s = response.readEntity(String.class);
MyEntity me = response.readEntity(MyEntity.class);
response.close();
```

#### Update

After you read the entity with `readEntity()`, the result of the reading is cached and is available with the call to `getEntity()`. This information doesn't really answer the OP's question, but I thought it was useful information to add in.