# How to extract the response body into post filter using zuul

Tags: java, spring, servlets, netflix-zuul

I'm working on a POC i need to use zuul as a sever to route 2 routes first will run normally but it has a custom post filter which will send another request to other api using some data of the response of the first requet,
so need to extract the response body of the first request into my custom post filter and get some specific attributes but i can not find the response as it always be null but the status code is 200.
how can i wait and get a value of specific attribute from the response and get the actual status code not just 200 as default value.

i tried to make this implementation using cloud gateway but i reached the same point of disability of extracting the response.
also i tried to make a response decorator but it failed too.

```
@Component
public class AddResponseHeaderFilter extends ZuulFilter {
@Override
public String filterType() {
    return "post";
}

@Override
public int filterOrder() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object run() {
    System.out.println("this is my filter");
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(context.getRequest());
    System.out.println(String.format("%s request to %s", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURL().toString()));
    HttpServletResponse servletResponse = context.getResponse();
    // return an address only
    System.out.println(context.getResponseBody().toString());
    servletResponse.addHeader("X-Foo", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    return null;
}
}
```

Comment: i do not need to write the request i need to get the response body to get some data from it to use into another request for another api not the same api, so i do not need to make wrapper for the input request, thanks

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679256/how-to-call-readentity-on-a-response-twice)

Answer (score 2):

`RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getResponseDataStream()` works fine for me, I am also able to manipulate the response.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import org.springframework.util.StreamUtils;
    
 RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
     HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
    String requestLog = StreamUtils.copyToString(request.getInputStream(), 
    Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```