# Read response body in JAX-RS client first as string and then as entity class without getting RESTEASY003765: Response is closed

Tags: java, jax-rs

Is it possible to do something like:

```
String responseAsString = 
String output = response.readEntity(String.class);
MyEntity entity = response.readEntity(MyDTO.class);
```

I would like to get the raw message as a string before converting it into a DTO.

Comment: Did you try to execute it? That's the right way to answer this question.

Comment: What do you mean by raw message, do you mean RAW message in String format ? If that is the case, you have already done it.

Comment: Yes, sorry I modified the question. I would like to use readEntity which can only be used once? There is a method called Object getEntity(); Maybe I have to use it?

Comment: Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47679256/how-to-call-readentity-on-a-response-twice